# Core Set ways of dealing with Magnum Opus

Tags: android-netrunner

So, admittedly, I'm brand new to Android: Netrunner. I only own the core set, I've only played five or six times, and I've only played as the Corp. I have moderately strong gaming experience, and while a bit rusty, know my way around building a deck. My wife, so far my only opponent, plays Shaper and every time has managed to get Magnum Opus up and running pretty quickly. The economy it provides, up to 8 credits a turn, is significant, especially with Kate lowering install costs.

I've only beaten her once (not counting a rule-naïve technical win our second match). I attribute this to her skill, of course, but also to that damn MO. The ice I install is almost always easily dealt with, since credits are often no object. Given the newness of the game and my opponent, my play style has been more exploratory than outright ruthless, but still:

Besides flatlining, or fast-advancing, or just being lucky, what are good strategies (again, I just have the core set) for dealing with the advantage of MO?

Comment: I've generally found the corp to be harder to win with.  The hacker seems to have many better options for making money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When playing a Runner who can reliably and easily out econ you the best way to win is to have a game plan that can ignore their econ.

**Flatlining**

This is probably best done out of Weyland in core. Splash some yellow tagging cards and [Snare!](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01070) and wait to blow their house up.
You can also try to do this with a Jinteki deck, but it will be much harder as core Jinteki does not have the econ to support this play style.

**Fast Advance**

With just core this is a little harder to do, as you do not have enough 3/2 agendas. Probably best done out of HP using [Biotic Labor](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01059) with some [San Sans](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01092) splashed in.

**Play Faster**

This should be your go to strategy for most games with core only. The Runner has inevitability, you need to win before they get there. With just the core set the Runner will have a hard time finding the cards they need. Shaper has no in-faction tutor in core, so will have to either just draw a ton or spend influence on special order (and still draw a ton to find MO). Take advantage of this, win before she has set up. Try to take a few more risks early game, scoring behind a single piece of ice when she does not have the correct breaker to go through it.

**Use Traps**

This strategy can be hard to pull off. It involves knowing your opponent and being able to bluff. However, it can be devastating. Pretending a [Junebug](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01069) is an agenda can win you the game. Or landing an [Aggressive Secretary](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01057) can blow up their rig, buying you time to score out before they can reassemble it.

**Play Sideways**

This is harder to do in core, but worth a try if you are feeling adventurous. The general idea here is to play mostly economy assets and upgrades. Spam them out, making many remote servers. The runner will have to waste valuable time and money to check and trash each of your servers. Mix in a few traps and after hitting one she may be more hesitant to check your remotes in the future, allowing you to "sneak" an agenda out with no protection. With core only, this is probably best done out of HB with some traps and San Sans splashed in.

**Use Defensive Upgrades/Buy Some Data Packs**

You can use upgrades to protect your Agendas. In core you are limited to [Red Herrings](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01091), which adds a nice tax but is not great if the runner has tons of money. If you want to play this way it may be best to invest a little more into the game and pick up some data packs. Specifically Double Time for [Caprice Nisei](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04114) and [RP](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02031) or What Lies Ahead for [Ash](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02013).
These are defensive upgrades that help you ignore a rich runner. Caprice brings server access down to a weighted coin flip in your favor. Ash relies on  a trace to force the Runner to try again. It is not the perfect solution to your problem but can help you get agendas out early before the runner is fully set up. Replicating Perfection (RP) is a Jinteki identity that helps you tax the runners clicks as well as money.

I also highly recommend you switch sides a few times. Playing as the Runner will give you a huge insight into how they play the game. What they are worried about, what they are looking for, when they feel safe. It will help you learn to exploit those weakness when you play Corp.

Comment: Yeah, good ideas. :) Quick note, as newer players may not be familiar with the term "tutor" - it just means an ability that lets you search your deck, e.g. SMC (http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03046)